# Cast int[] into MyType[] where MyType inherited from Enum?

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, enums

I try to cast an int array `int[]` into `Rights` array `Rights[]`, `Rights` is `Enum` by example... But it can be other type than rights but always inherited from `Enum`.
I got the final type in a `Type` variable.
I can create the `Enum[]` array but not the final `Rights[]` array for my `methodInfo.Invoke(obj,param.ToArray())`.

```
List<object> param = new List<object>();
ParameterInfo pi = ...
if (pi.ParameterType.IsArray && pi.ParameterType.GetElementType().IsEnum)
{
    List<Enum> enums = new List<Enum>();
    foreach (int i in GetTabInt())
    {
        enums.Add((Enum)Enum.ToObject(pi.ParameterType.GetElementType(), i));
    }
    param.Add(enums.ToArray()); // got Enum[] not Rights[]
}
```

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: What are you doing with this array afterwards? Depending on what you do with it, you *may* just be able to add the result of `GetTabInt()` (or a clone) to the parameter list, as the CLR allows conversions between arrays like this. Yes, `enums.ToArray()` will create an `Enum[]` because that's the list type - but if we can see a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: @How do you inherit from an `Enum`?

Comment: How about: `enums.Select(e => (Rights)e).ToArray()` ?

Comment: I cant write "Rights" in my code, because the effective type is in a Type variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array of the appropriate type.  Since the type isn't known at compile time, you must use `Array.CreateInstance()`.  You can use this helper method.

```
public Array ToEnumArray(Type type, ICollection values)
{
    if (!typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Type '{0}' is not an Enum", type));
    var result = Array.CreateInstance(type, values.Count);
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var value in values)
        result.SetValue(Enum.ToObject(type, value), i++);
    return result;
}
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
ParameterInfo pi = ...;
if (pi.ParameterType.IsArray && pi.ParameterType.GetElementType().IsEnum)
{
    var enumArray = ToEnumArray(pi.ParameterType.GetElementType(), GetTabInt());
    param.Add(enumArray);
}
```

Comment: This works. I tried Activator.CreateInstance but not Array.CreateInstance.